# how to extract high 256 bits of 512 bits __m512i using avx512 intrinsic?

Tags: avx512

In AVX2 intrinsic programming, we can use _mm256_extracti128_si256 to extract high/low 128 bits of 256 bits, but I don't find such intrinsics function for 512 bits register to extract high/low 256 bits. How to extract high 256 bits of 512 bits __m512i using avx2 intrinsic?

Answer (score 3):

There are no AVX2 intrinsics to operate on a type that's new in AVX-512, `__m512i`.

There are **AVX-512 intrinsics** for `vextracti32x8` (`_mm512_extracti32x8_epi32`) and `vextracti64x4` (`_mm512_extracti64x4_epi64`) and mask / maskz versions (which is why two different element-size versions of the instructions exist).

You can find them by [searching](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE_ALL,AVX_512,Other&ig_expand=6243,519&text=__m256i%252525252525252525252525252520_mm512&avxnewtechs=FMA) in Intel's intrinsics guide for `__m256i _mm512` (i.e. for `_mm512` intrinsics that return an `__m256i`).  Or you can search for `vextracti64x4`; the intrinsics guide search feature works on asm mnemonics.  Or look through https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ which is scraped from Intel's vol.2 asm manual; search for `extract` quickly gets to some likely-looking asm instructions; each entry has a section for intrinsics (for instructions that have intrinsics).

There's also `_mm512_castsi512_si256` for the low half, of course. That's a no-op (zero asm instructions), so there aren't different element-size versions of it with merge-masking or zero-masking.

```
  __m256i low  = _mm512_castsi512_si256    (v512);
  __m256i high = _mm512_extracti32x8_epi32 (v512, 1);
```

There's also [`vshufi64x2` and similar](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vshuff32x4:vshuff64x2:vshufi32x4:vshufi64x2) to shuffle with 128-bit granularity, with an 8-bit immediate control mask to grab lanes from 2 source vectors.  (Like `shufps` does for 4-byte elements).  That and a cast can get a 256-bit vector from any combination of parts you want.